# How to write unit test for WEB API Http Method and Custom Route

Tags: unit-testing, routes, asp.net-web-api2, mstest

I need to write unit test for, 1) web api method has [HTTPPOST] method type and 2) web api method has route attribute [api/Verification].

Can any one suggest, how to write test to do this.

I found one of the way for web api route verification using http://www.vannevel.net/2015/03/08/50/ but RouteAssert is not found.

I am writing unit test using MSTest.

Tried below way to find descriptor so, can check for route and httpmethods, problem is, its giving null for methodInfo.

```
private HttpActionDescriptor GetAction(AccountAPIController controller, string name)
{
    try
    {        
        MethodInfo methodInfo = controller.GetType().GetMethod(name, new Type[] { controller.GetType(), controller.GetType() });
        return new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor { MethodInfo = methodInfo, Configuration = controller.Configuration, ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor()};
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }

}
```

Comment: That blog is using a 3rd party library to test the routes. You could basically do an in-memory integration test using `HttpServer`. Does your controller have any dependencies? Show the controller under test, how your tried to test it in a [mcve] and let's see if we can help.

Comment: Added code above what i tried.

Comment: That is the test?

Comment: Inside test method, calling this private method to retrive action info and then, will validate in testmethod for route and httpmethod types.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by reflection to verify for class and method attributes. It works finally.

Thanks.